# Moving doxygen comments from source to header

Tags: c++, documentation-generator

Are there any tools available to automate moving Doxygen comments from source files to the corresponding headers? Nothing listed on the [Helper tools and scripts](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html) page seems to handle that, and I've not had any luck with Google either.

#### Background

We've been putting most of our doxygen comments in sources, but not we need to distribute that documentation without the sources themselves. Since doxygen output includes the contents of the files used while generating, we need to migrate everything to the corresponding headers. Given that it's a pretty substantial code base, I'd like to automate the task (at least mostly), but would prefer to use an off-the-shelf tool before hacking together my own.

Comment: Do you need to supply the documentation or the files from which the documentation is generated? In the first case it is not necessary that the source is visible as long as you set `SOURCE_BROWSER=NO`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't though to check if it could be disabled. That works better than I'd planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case just the documentation is to be delivered it can be sufficient to set the configuration setting: `SOURCE_BROWSER=NO` in the `Doxyfile`.

It might also be necessary to check other settings as well like: `EXTRACT_...`, `CALL...GRAPHS`, `REFERENCE...` and other implementation 'revealing' commands.